# Rbenv warning: line 1: ge#!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I use rbenv for a little while now and I start getting this warning everytime I run a ruby command or when I launch a rake task :

`/Users/.../.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 1: ge#!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory`

or

`/Users/.../.rbenv/shims/rake: line 1: ge#!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory`

And of course, `/usr/bin/env` actually exists and works.

Comment: From the leading "ge" in the error, I would assume the line ending on the shebang is incorrect.

Comment: Alright...! Thanks! I haven't seen that .rbenv/shims/ruby was just a script.